# Push a subdirectory in a Git project to a different Git project

Tags: git, github

In my build script in a project (that is in our private Git) it copies all the samples we have to a working folder. I want to push that folder to a public Git project of ours. I don't need it to be [registered at that location as a sub Git project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415243/how-to-nest-a-git-project-in-a-git-project), I just need to push all the files, including subdirectories, up to a distinct Git project.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Either make it a submodule, or copy all the files to a separate folder in a separate git repository and then commit and push over there.

Comment: Copy history of the subdirectory using `git subtree push -P <name-of-folder> <new-empty-repo>` into a separate repository. From there pull using `git subtree pull` into the target repo. Push the target repo back to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want the subfolder, without your main project to realize said subfolder is pushed, you can:

- initialize a new Git repository on GitHub
- clone it locally
- add the files of that subfolder to your local clone, commit and push

The trick is, in the new local repository, to designate as a working tree your current folder inside your other project

```
cd /path/to/local/new/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/main/project/subfolder add .
git commit -m "Add subfolder"
git push -u origin master
```